# Can I use the adjective 'facile' in the form of 'facile with _____'?

Tags: word-usage

The only definitions I come across for 'facile' are in its adjective form. 'Facile', followed by the noun being described.

Is it grammatically or colloquially acceptable to use the word in the manner of: "the girl is facile with data"?

Comment: Generally, ***facile*** means ***easy, simple***. But your girl is ***at ease*** with data (she's ***comfortable*** and ***familiar*** with it, she knows how to deal with it), which isn't a suitable context for the word ***facile*** (the relevant data might actually be extremely complex, we have no idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/synonym-of-the-day/facile-2020-07-26/) has a treatment better than that in many dictionaries (but amended below):

> **facile** [adjective]  [often interchangeable with *easy*]
>
> Something that is easy is by definition not hard or difficult. When an
> activity or goal can be carried out or achieved with little difficulty
> or effort, it may be called facile.
>
> - *A facile victory*, for instance, is a victory won handily with minimal exertion.
> - Similarly, someone who is *facile with words* expresses themself with ease.
>
> While these senses of *facile* at least connote skillfulness, facile
> sometimes sports an air of superficiality:
>
> - *facile answers* are overly simplistic or trite responses to difficult questions;
> - *facile assumptions* are things taken for granted that really shouldn't be; and
> - *facile arguments* are shallow lines of reasoning—all things formed or arrived at a little too easily.
>
> Collocations: *a facile win, a facile victory*
>
> - *The team sailed to a facile victory.*

On the surface, this would seem to license 'She is facile with N' where N is a suitable noun, and 'data' looks like a good candidate for N. However, [these Google 3grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=facile+with+words%2Cfacile+with+English%2Cfacile+with+computers%2Cfacile+with+computing%2Cfacile+with+data&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfacile%20with%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfacile%20with%20English%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfacile%20with%20computers%3B%2Cc0) indicate that 'facile with data' is *very much less idiomatic* than 'facile with words' (and even 'facile with computers').
[image]

I'd use 'well at home with handling data'.

Comment: I think *facile with data* is perfectly fine. *Facile with words* is a relatively common collocation, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use *facile* with anything else.

Comment: @PeterShor: I forgot about ***facile with words***. That format works for me with ***language*** (also ***of pen, of speech,...***) and doubtless several other nouns. But the usage seems inherently "literary / dated" to me, and almost all nouns that work at all for me seem to be concerned with "communication". I don't like it at all as an "up-to-the-minute" usage with *[big, computer-generated] **data***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Facile with his brush* used to be pretty common, too. It seems to me it's a clash of register ... *facile* is more of a 19th century word, while *data* is more of a 21-century word. It doesn't bother me, but obviously it sounds wrong to some people.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, that was *exactly* what bothered me! The clash of register. I was going to say it's the linguistic equivalent of (technological) "cyberpunk", but it's just dawned on me that (to me at least), "cyberpunk artwork" always implies some kind of hybrid between modern IT and *Victorian* technology (fusion-powered airships, steam-powered space rockets, or whatever). But derogatory ***facile = trivially simple*** is now so well established I think it would be better to avoid the older usage unless you know your audience is at least slightly on the "fuddy-duddy" side.

Comment: Different take: That is a *facile argument* is shorter than: That is an argument that is easy **to make**. As for facile with x, that stretches the ear....This is easy with computers. [i.e. easy to do]. This is facile with computers. Sounds "orrible".